# Sending an attachment in mail using a variable as data container python

Tags: python, string, variables, email-attachments

I'd like to know if it was possible to send a variable (say a string) as an attachment in a mail using python. The goal is to avoid the making of temporary files in the process.

As an example, I'd like to send a string which is formatted as a csv as an attachment to a mail and possibly this attachment could later be downloaded as a file on the other end of the tunnel.

Thanks for all of your possible help.

EDIT: It now works with StringIO, thank you for your help. Answer below

Comment: You can send a string as an attachment. It doesn't matter whether that string is in a variable, in an element of a list, or a temporary value resulting from some function call. If you show us the code you're using to send emails (or at least tell us what library you're using), we can show you how to send attachments. If not, the best I can offer is (1) read the docs for whichever library you're using; (2) if you can't find a function that takes a string, but can find one that takes an open file object, try using an `io.StringIO`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look further into this and post the code after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the working method that I am now using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7.x
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
#Imports
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
import sys
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except:
    print("Could not import critical library StringIO")
    sys.exit(0)
import smtplib
import datetime

def run_mail(self):

    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    dateAAAAMMDD = str(date.year) + "_" + str( date.month) + "_" +str( date.day)


    pj1 = StringIO(self.pj1_data)
    pj1_name = "my_att_name_" + str(dateAAAAMMDD) + ".csv"

    pj2 = StringIO(self.pj2_data)
    pj2_name = "my_att_name2_" + str(dateAAAAMMDD) + ".txt"

    pj3 = StringIO(self.pj3_data)
    pj3_name = "my_att_name3_" + str(dateAAAAMMDD) + ".txt"

    pj =[(pj1,pj1_name), (pj2,pj2_name), (pj3,pj3_name)]

    fromaddr = 'address@something.com'
    toaddr = 'toanotheraddress@something.com'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    subject = 'subject dated ' + dateAAAAMMDD
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = subject 

    msg.attach(MIMEText("Auto-generated script", 'plain'))

    for data, att_name in pj :
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(data.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % att_name)
        msg.attach(part)
    server_port = 25
    server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver.com',server_port)
    server.starttls()
    #If login required, not very secure, use either input or localhost without
    #login required
    server.login(fromaddr, 'MyPasswordGoesHere') 

    content = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,content)


    server.quit()
```